# How to make a minimal reproducible example with survey data that include BRR weights?

Tags: r

I am trying to learn how to create minimal reproducible examples (MRE) in order to be able to get better R help using complex survey data that involves 200 BRR weight variables.  I am using Lumley's Survey Package.  I have tried subsetting the data set prior to creating the svyrepdesign object in order to only involve only a few of the BRR weight variables (with many different approaches) and it creates all sorts of errors.  If I create the svyrepdesign object with all 200 of the BRR weight variables, it is a very cumbersome MRE to use with the dput() function into an R Script file, even just using the head() function to get the first 5 cases.  Any advisement would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does anyone know if R has a web snippet service yet, a la play.rust-lang.org or jsbin?

Answer (score 0):

In cases where minimal complete is too huge to be posted on SO the best thing to do is to put your dataset onto external storage (like github) and in your R code posted in question here first 2-3 lines will be downloading that. E.g.

```
library(RCurl)
data <- getURL("https://raw.github.com/user/repository/master/file.csv")
```

In cases where it's a standard dataset, you can similarly post commands loading that

```
library(datasets)
# this is where my 'airquality' comes from
```

It is also worth explaining the structure if it's not too long and download size.

If whatever you do takes more than a screen of text to describe - probably it's worth thinking about that a bit longer to naturally split a smaller specific question to ask.